# JSON as Javascript object in Azure http trigger function

Tags: node.js, json, azure, azure-functions

```
const df = require("durable-functions");

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const client = df.getClient(context);
    
    context.log(`Function Name = '${req.params.functionName}'.`);
    context.log(`Body = '${req.body}'.`);
    const instanceId = await client.startNew(req.params.functionName, undefined, req.body);

    context.log(`Started orchestration with ID = '${instanceId}'.`);

    return client.createCheckStatusResponse(context.bindingData.req, instanceId);
};
```

I have tried to use POSTMAN or https://reqbin.com/ for testing but I always get object.
It is a simple case but I don't understand why it is not JSON object.

[image: Log example]

[image: Postman example]

I read this one
[TypeScript Azure Function Read Body of POST method as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62248764/typescript-azure-function-read-body-of-post-method-as-json)
but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine!
It is already deserialized json object.
It looks like the normal string in a log after

```
JSON.stringify(req.body)
```

My fault was that I wrongly got it in the orchestrator function from the context.